# How to create a custom back press button?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am new to flutter and curious if we can create a custom back press button, not the one in appbar.
Just like a normal  button that takes back to previous screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you so that:

1. Create a raw material button
2. Add the on press method to decide which screen it goes to.
3. In you main.dart, under the routes method, import the screen you want to push the current screen back to and then call it something.
4. Inside your onPress() method, you can call `Navigator.pushNamed(context, routeName)`.
5. Now you can customise this raw material button as much as you want. Here are some of the main properties you can set:
   textStyle
   fillColor
   elevation
   padding
   constraints
   shape
   child
6. Now give a name to this custom button you have created by extracting it into a widget.
7. Call the widget inside your code! If you want it to be aligned at the top left, which is usually where you find it:

```
Align(
alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
 child: CustomButton()
),
```

Enjoy! PS: If you need any help, feel free to ask me and I will assist you to my best abilities!